# Connect to Sharepoint through Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sharepoint, active-directory

How do I connect to Sharepoint (e.g. fetching lists) through Cocoa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Cocoa Web Service API](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/UsingWebservices/Introduction/Introduction.html) to access the [SharePoint Web Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479390.aspx?ppud=4).

I don't think anyone has written an article specifically about accessing the SharePoint web services from cocoa, but [here is one](https://lists.apple.com/archives/Macnetworkprog/2006/Apr/msg00038.html) for connecting to .Net web services from cocoa.